# Extjs: change params value while loading store

Tags: arrays, asynchronous, extjs4, store

I have a store which I need to call it multiple times with different parameter value. parameter values are in an array and I need to call the store with array order. How can I change params value inside load method?

```
  var i = 0;
  me.getMyStore().load({
            params: {id: ids[i]},
            scope: this,
            callback: function(records, operation, success) {
            // I need to increase value of i by 1 but it doesn't work like this
            i++;
            }
   })
```

Comment: Store loading is asynchronous.

Comment: yes I know. but is there any way to keep my arrays order to load the store?

Comment: The only guaranteed way would be to wait in the callback and then load the next one. However your approach seems wrong, I'd suggest you look for an alternate solution.

Comment: Thank you Evan but Actually I posted this question to find the alternate solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use method `sort` method to order your store. (Documentation — http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sort)

Like this:

```
store.sort([
        {
            property  : 'PropertyName1',
            direction : 'DESC'
        },
        {
            property  : 'PropertyName2',
            direction : 'ASC'
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to sort my store. My store returns only one item. I need to have an order for loading each store. me.getMyStore().load({ params: { id : id }})

Comment: It's very strange thing you're trying to do. You can try `batch`  mechanism http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Batch

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem, I still need to call my store by order. Why is it strange? There are many tree nodes from a drag and drop event and I need to first create the parent and then its children.